# Dynamically added paper-button is not rendered correctly

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have the following html:

```
  <paper-button raised>Static</paper-button>
  <script>
    var button = document.createElement('paper-button');
    button.textContent = "dynamic";
    button.raised = true;
    document.body.appendChild(button);
  </script>
```

If I add the paper-button statically, it renders normally, but I have do allmost the exact same thing dynamically, I don't get any animations.

Is there something special I need to do if I add the paper-button dynamically ?

see: http://jsbin.com/rararurotu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Probably because `paper-button` isn't live bound. That is, it only works on elements present in the DOM at the time of script load.

Comment: @Jan Not sure what you are exactly saying. Can't I add a paper button dynamically in polymer 1 ?

Comment: At least not the way you are trying to. Check if they have any methods for creating and adding elements. And check the documentation if you're supposed to be creating elements yourself through JS at all, I'm guessing not.

Comment: @Jan in the docs they also create it through JS, see: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#register-element

Comment: I see no evidence that JS-creating the element is supported https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-button.html Again, check the documentation if this is the way you're supposed to be adding dynamic elements and not through some sort of binding.

Comment: try to add it to a <template is="dom-bind"> instead of body see if that works

Comment: @Jan I appreciate that you are trying to help, but you don't seem to know anything about Polymer, and just saying that I should read documentation is not really helping anybody. I have read all the docs at least 2x times btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `textContent` using the Polymer.dom api.

The following code will work:

```
<paper-button raised>static</paper-button>
<script>
  var button = document.createElement('paper-button');
  button.raised = true;
  Polymer.dom(button).textContent = 'dynamic';
  document.body.appendChild(button);
</script>
```

see: http://jsbin.com/gexifaxaqi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Kasper, that's exactly right - since you are just *consuming* polymer elements from index.html, your script code is probably the best approach. Matthew's answer, while useful, is on *producing* your own custom component, which I infer from your question is not applicable to you.

Answer (score 2):

In Polymer 1.0, there are a couple of ways to do this.

### Option 1 (using `document.createElement`)

*Update: I think @Kasper's response is a better approach when using Polymer.dom because it allows us to insert textContent directly instead of via an internal class.*

```
<!-- my-dom-element.html -->
<link href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="my-dom-element">
  <template>
    <div>
      <paper-button raised>button 1</paper-button>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-dom-element',
      ready: function () {
        var button = document.createElement('paper-button');
        button.raised = true;
        button.querySelector('.content').textContent = 'button 2';
        Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(button);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

See [`Polymer.dom`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html) for more info.

### Option 2 (idiomatic, using conditional templates)

Here we use Polymer's native language to create the button element based on a condition (in this case, a property value).

```
<!-- my-conditional-dom-element.html -->
<link href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="my-conditional-dom-element">
  <template>
    <div>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{success}}">
        <paper-button raised>
          Conditional Button
        </paper-button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-conditional-dom-element',
      properties:  {
        success: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: true
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

See [helper elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html) for more info.

My personal take is that Polymer's DSL for creating components is fairly clean and, where possible, it is good to take advantage of that.

Comment: What do you think of the way in my answer below ? It also seems to work.

Comment: I think that is a great approach if we want to use Polymer.dom to create the element.